# Example for video_set_callbacks vlc python binding

Tags: python, callback, vlc, libvlc

Could someone share a python code snippet showing how to use video_set_callbacks in libvlc ?

My intermediate goal is to retrieve a frame each time it is ready to be displayed.
A solution would normally be interesting [not only for me](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=104613&p=355000&hilit=python%20callback#p355000).

Thanks!